# Are We Fast And Furious?

Tags: code-golf, decision-problem, regular-expression, text-processing

There are currently nine feature length films in the core *Fast & Furious/The Fast and the Furious* media franchise, a series of films about bald men scowling and driving cars very fast. The names of the films, as can be seen, follow a completely logical and sensible convention:

- *The Fast and the Furious*
- *2 Fast 2 Furious*
- *The Fast and the Furious: Tokyo Drift*
- *Fast & Furious*
- *Fast Five*
- *Fast & Furious 6*
- *Furious 7*
- *The Fate of the Furious*
- *F9*

I'm a Hollywood producer working on the new, tenth *Fast & Furious* film, and I'm struggling to find a title which hasn't yet been used. Please write me a piece of code - as short as possible - which takes in my input string, and returns a truthy value if **any** of the following are true:

1. the input string is already an existing *Fast & Furious* film title
2. the input string differs from an existing *Fast & Furious* film title *only* by replacing an existing number with `ten` or `10`
3. the input string differs from an existing *Fast & Furious* film title *only* by replacing `&` with `and` (or vice versa).

For instance, all of these strings would return a **truthy** value:

- *The Fast and the Furious* (matches check 1)
- *The Fast & the Furious* (matches check 3)
- *Fast and Furious 10* (matches checks 2 and 3)
- *10 Fast 2 Furious* (matches check 2)
- *Furious Ten* (matches check 2)
- *F10* and *FTEN* (match check 2)

And all of these strings would return a **falsy** value:

- *The Fast or The Furious*
- *Fast Times at Ridgemont High*
- *Fast/Furious 10*
- *Too Fast Too Furious*
- *Ten Furious*
- *Fast Ten Furious*
- *The Fast and the Furious: Kyoto Cruise*

*Fate of the Furious*, as a pun, is obviously a tricky case. Unless you're very driven, you don't need to support puns, just exact text matches. If you can create a new *Fast & Furious* film title which is a pun, please share.

**Clarifications**

- The matching is not case-sensitive, so the input string can be in lowercase. The film company design team will work out how to depict your title on the posters anyway, and the answer is 'in red, with speedy lines'.
- I've clarified that the numbering match should only be true if an existing number in the title has been replaced with the string `10` or `ten`.

Comment: [Welcome to Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20861/66833) and nice first question! For future reference, we recommend using the [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges) to get feedback on challenge ideas before posting them to main. We require all questions to have an [objective winning criteria](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8130/why-do-we-have-objective-winning-criteria) to be scored. I'd suggest [code-golf] (shortest code), and that you should add some falsey test cases

Comment: If matching numbering by english is required, this will need a bit more clarification on what exactly counts as a number and what doesn't. For example, is forty nine a number, or only forty-nine; is it one hundred or a hundred or does just hundred suffice, etc. I think it might not be a bad idea to just make it so "differs by numbering" needs to only handle numbers as digits, since all of the original titles just have digits too.

Comment: Is this case-sensitive or can we perhaps take the input in, say, lowercase?

Comment: @hyper-neutrino Ah, if only that were true! 'Fast Five' is the exception. I am however happy to specify that only the digits 1-9 need to be checked.

Comment: Oops, my bad. I clearly am terrible at reading :P

Comment: @Neil Great question! It is not case-sensitive: the design team will work out how to depict your title on the posters anyway.

Comment: @hyper-neutrino Don't worry, the Fast & Furious producers are bad at naming films.

Comment: When you say Fast Five is the exception, does that mean Fast 10/Fast ten should be truthy?

Comment: As it stands, test case `Fast and Furious 10 (matches checks 2 and 3)` appears inconsistent with the rules.  This is derived from `Fast & Furious 6` by changing a number AND by substituting `& -> and` but checks 2 and 3 (as written) say ONLY one change (not both.)

Comment: New name: ````The Fast and the Franchise````

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 190 bytes

```python
lambda a:re.match("(the '!the %(: tokyo drift)?|(2# ' (2# %|'!%|' (five#|'!% (6#|% (7#|the fate of the %|f(9#)$".translate({33:" (and|&) ",35:"|10|ten)",39:"fast",37:"furious"}),a)
import re
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lZBBasMwEEX3OcVEauIRhGDHtCGG0ot0o9ZSLWpLRhoXQtWzu7LTFEy66UKfGc3/85D6MzXOlqN@fB5b2b3UEmTl1b6T9NogQ2oUZOtJN1gBufezg9obTeIp4oFDBpNuYrZOB1CbD8WnBvCBx6RHHqewlqTAaZgXRY0nLu7Ynry0oU0j/CzLigFKW8etALYr7ysWizySsiJ1p4ppGShVx1QN3rghsC@xk2Jlut55Aq/G3htLqJFdgIEgrZuJ14QQq1vT9p@WxS8s/L/MHycU@WJe5Jd1hz9p11B68uI@DL3y4Lx5M1a2cAMhQ60CPrPGbw)

A very naive attempt at this.

Comment: This is super! It doesn't match 'F10', which I've now added into the truthy values section as it's a special case without whitespace.

Comment: @lowercasename it matches `f10` since i assume lowercase; is that alright or should i special case capital F here?

Comment: Oh, my mistake! You're completely fine!